# How can I use plugins in TorBrowser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, plugin

I visited a streaming site in TorBrowser, but it said it needed a plugin to stream videos. I've already installed the latest version of Adobe Flash Player, but it still won't stream videos or play Flash games. What can I do to make streaming video work in TorBrowser?

Comment: if my answer helped you, please accept it by clicking the checkmark to the left.

Answer (score 10):

Plugins like Adobe Flash and Java are disabled by default in TorBrowser. This is due to the fact that they are outside of Tor developers' control, and contain known problems which can be used to coerce your real IP address from your browser.

If you still want to use these plugins, you can visit `about:addons`, click the Plugins tab, and change "Never Activate" to "Ask to Activate" next to the plugin you want to run. This will cause TorBrowser to prompt you each time a website requests to run a plugin. If you don't want this prompt, change the dropdown to "Always Activate" - but be aware that *this will open up the possibility of your real IP leaking, compromising your anonymity and rendering TorBrowser useless*. This is the least secure option and I would highly recommend against it if you are serious about using Tor properly.

Comment: So to understand this, you can't watch or download images or videos while in the Tor Network, not without showing your IP?

Comment: You *can* watch videos, just not those that require third-party add-ons or applications to run. Sites are now starting to move across to native HTML5 in place of flash, which is a good thing. (e.g. YouTube earlier this year.)