# Can I install Dashlane extension on Tor Browser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I'm on a MacBook Pro. Can I install the Dashlane extension on Tor Browser? How?

When I try through Dashlane it says: "Update error. Retrying in a few minutes," but the message never goes away, and Tor does not appear in the browsers listed in Preferences, that I could click to have Dashlane install the extension.

Answer (score 2):

> If I can/do install the Dashlane extension, **do I remain anonymous**?

Dashline is a closed-source, third-party add-on. As the source code isn't available, you have [no way of knowing what it's doing](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/1345/1730). It could be bypassing any proxy settings, including Tor entirely, revealing your real IP address. Add-ons also add to your unique [browser fingerprint](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/536/what-is-browser-fingerprinting-what-is-linkability?rq=1).

Add-ons and extensions are generally [recommended against](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#TBBOtherExtensions) for exactly these reasons.

The same argument can be used to explain why using vanilla Firefox proxied through Tor - instead of the Tor Browser Bundle - is a bad thing. You don't know how Firefox might by bypassing the proxy. (For the many anonymity-related changes that have gone into the Browser Bundle, see the [Browser Bundle Design](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design/) document. See [here](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6589/what-are-the-changes-made-to-firefox-in-the-tbb) for an associated discussion.)

If you really *have* to install the add-on, then try first allowing add-ons in the `config:addons` settings, as per [these](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/1484/1730) instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular Firefox browser connected to Tor via FoxyProxy, don't use a bundled one. It's a different version : old version with backported patches from new ones, so it's API/behaviour is odd sometimes, and it does not allows some extensions to work normal. feel free to ask if you have further questions

Comment: See @Richard's answer why this might not be the preferred solution.

Comment: @AndrewLott In My Humble Opinion any password manager is evil : it can be ten times open-source, but hacked and all your passwords are Gone with the Wind(ows) =)

Comment: This is why Tails includes KeePassX, storing passwords in an encrypted database on an encrypted device.